# determine all the ideals of $\Bbb Z\times \Bbb Z$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

I have only been able to determine three ideals:
A maximal that is $\Bbb Z\times 2\Bbb Z$.
A prime $\Bbb Z\times \{0\}$
Finally a proper ideal $\Bbb Z\times 4\Bbb Z$. I don't know if there will be more ideals, some help to be able to determine them all.

Comment: This may help: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3345579/proof-about-ideals-of-cartesian-product-of-rings. Similarly: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/101214/structure-of-ideals-in-the-product-of-two-rings?rq=1 and https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3583208/every-ideal-of-the-ring-r-times-s-where-r-and-s-are-rings-is-the-cartesian?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: Also asked [yesterday](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4446215/29335) (now deleted by the author). If it's a classmate maybe you two should start a study group.